# How to Understand the "DNX SDK" and the "Framework" in the Asp.Net 5 Project

Tags: dnx

I'm a little confused about some terms in the next version of ASP.Net

1. we can set the default dnx version in the DNVM
2. we can specify dnx sdk version in the global.json of the solution
3. we can set the frameworks (dnx451, dnxcore50) in the project
4. we can specify runtime on the property page of the web app project.

How do these settings work on the dev machine (ie have much version of dnx installed) and production machine?

Thanks
Frank

Comment: What version of the ASP.NET Beta do you have? Have you updated to the latest 1.0.0-Beta7?        In production, things are much like they are in dev.  The DNX SDK ships as part of your application, rather than shipping as a component of Windows itself. This is a central reason why DNX exists.

Comment: Thanks! I'm using beta7, but I just don't understand what's the sdk version in global.json vs frameworks in project.json vs runtime on project property page

Comment: The project property page controls the tooling in the IDE.  The content of the global.json is intended, I believe, to be the master. Why you would EVER want to have these legitimately be different I do not understand. I think they must always be the same, and thus, I believe, that if the Tooling (the IDE plugins for ASP.NET) lets them get into different places, that it's a bug. But I'm just a rather new user to this so I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The runtime story**

- About (1) DNVM sets the default runtime which is used when the project is executed  (if the runtime is not provided as a local deployed package).
- About (2) The global.json specify the runtime which is used in Visual Studio when opening the solution (since there could be projects with many different sdks) ([Design Notes ASP.Net Team](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/DesignNote-19th-Jan-2015)). No usage beyond development in  my understanding.
- About (4) Like noted in the comments, the property page of the project is basically the framework which is used for debugging when you start the debugging in this project, but seems like global.json is the master. No usage beyond development in  my understanding.

I have not found any proper documentation on it beyond the design notes between these three things.

**The build story**

- About (3). The specified frameworks (dnx451, dnxcore50) in the project.json are build targets for the nuget package (which contains separate dlls for both targets). The library builds separately for the dnx451 and dnxcore50 environments and is packaged into one nuget package. Make sure you understand also the target "dotnet" in difference to "dnx451" and "dnxcore50". Once the application is deployed DNX will take the right dll from the nuget package (or during packaging of the overall app before).